# Get summary by country with Fleet Telematics API

Tags: here-api

I want to use Fleet Telematics API and get information about traffic time/travel time and distance by country similar to what is described [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html). As you can see this is supported in Routing API but it does not support "bus" as a TransportMode.

I tried to use "rollups" query param but it only aggregates toll costs by country not distance and time which I'm looking for. Is there a way to achieve this with Fleet Telematics API?

Comment: please refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-route-summary.html for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this accomplished your task.

```
http://cre.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id={}&app_code={}&overlays=OVERLAYMYMAP&mode=fastest;bus;traffic:enabled&waypoint0=geo!50.8857,14.81589&waypoint1=geo!50.8681536,14.8308207
```

for more information.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-routing-extension/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculateroute.html